# Regex Expression help - python

Tags: python, regex

I need help from some Regex Guru's. I have been struggling on this one for a little while and can't get it working as intended.

This is my regex patter at the moment - it get everything between ',' and ')'

`df['regex_2'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'\,(.*?)\)')`

```
Text 123 (SDC, XUJ)
Text BCD (AUD)
Text 123 (AUD, XTJ)
Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)


` XUJ`
``
` XTJ`
`TACT,HGI7649AU`
```

However, what I need is all characters after the last comma before the bracket. Please see examples below.

```
Text 123 (SDC, XUJ)
Text BCD (AUD)
Text 123 (AUD, XTJ)
Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)


`XUJ`
`` 
`XTJ`
`HGI7649AU`
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern used matches *any* character after the comma, including commas themselves:

`r'\,(.*?)\)'`

In the following test case this yields both tokens after the first comma because `,` is a matching character:

`Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU) -> TACT,HGI7649AU`

One way to achieve the goal of only capturing the token after the last comma and before the parenthesis is to instead match on all characters *excluding* commas by using the syntax `[^,]`:

`r',\s*([^,]*)\)'`

- `\s` is added to match zero or more occurrences of space so that they are not included in the capture group
- `^,` is interpreted as "all characters *except* `,`"
- `?` is removed from the capture group since the preceding token is already optional

**Example:**

```python
In: re.search(r',\s*([^,]*)\)', 'Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)').group(1)

Out: 'HGI7649AU'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value *"after the last comma before the bracket."* you can use a capture group:

```
\([^()]*,([^()]+)\)
```

In parts, the pattern matches

- `\(` Match the opening parenthesis
- `[^()]*,` Match any char except `(` and `)` and then match a comma
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^()]+` Match 1+ times any char except `(` and `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match the closing parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5nQvc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1CJJYP)

Example

```
strings = [
    "Text 123 (SDC, XUJ)",
    "Text BCD (AUD)",
    "Text 123 (AUD, XTJ)",
    "Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)",
]

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["name"])
df['regex_2'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'\([^()]*,([^()]+)\)')
df = df.fillna('')
print(df)
```

Output

```
                             name    regex_2
0             Text 123 (SDC, XUJ)        XUJ
1                  Text BCD (AUD)           
2             Text 123 (AUD, XTJ)        XTJ
3  Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)  HGI7649AU
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you prefer using `Series.str.replace`, you can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["Text 123 (SDC, XUJ)", "Text BCD (AUD)", "Text 123 (AUD, XTJ)", "Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)"]})
df['result'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'.*,\s*([^()]*).*|.+', r'\1', regex=True)
# => df
#                              name     result
# 0             Text 123 (SDC, XUJ)        XUJ
# 1                  Text BCD (AUD)           
# 2             Text 123 (AUD, XTJ)        XTJ
# 3  Text BCSS (AUD,TACT,HGI7649AU)  HGI7649AU
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eigGHg/1). *Details*:

- `.*,\s*([^()]*).*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, then a comma, then zero or more whitespaces, then Group 1 capturing zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`, and then the rest of the line
- `|` - or
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The replacement is `\1`, the value of Group 1.